# sbt meta-build dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a project/Generate.scala that generates some Scala code destined for sourceManaged. Generate.scala has its own dependencies.  From the sbt documentation, it seems that those dependencies should go into project/build.sbt.  When I tried that, sbt stops resolving my plugins declared in project/plugins.sbt.

What's the right way to declare these dependencies? And how should I think about the meta-build conceptually? It looks like I misunderstand ["sbt is recursive."](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Organizing-Build.html)

project/build.sbt:

```
scalaVersion in ThisBuild:= "2.12.2"

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")
resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("scalameta", "maven")

libraryDependencies += "org.scalameta" %% "scalameta" % "1.7.0"
```

project/plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.earldouglas" % "xsbt-web-plugin" % "3.0.1")
addSbtPlugin("io.get-coursier" % "sbt-coursier" % "1.0.0-M15")
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.16")
addSbtPlugin("com.thesamet" % "sbt-protoc" % "0.99.6" exclude ("com.trueaccord.scalapb", "protoc-bridge_2.10"))

libraryDependencies += "com.trueaccord.scalapb" %% "compilerplugin-shaded" % "0.6.0-pre3"
```